# Delete selected token from NSTokenField

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nstokenfield

I'm trying to add a delete selected tag action to a button to delete the selected token/s in a NSTokenField.

```
@IBAction func deleteSelectedTag(sender: AnyObject) {
    let fieldEditor = (tagTokenField.cell() as! NSCell).fieldEditorForView(tagTokenField)
    if fieldEditor?.selectedRanges.count > 0 {
        fieldEditor?.delete
    }
}
```

This code does not delete the selected token/s. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to do this, was to edit the array that the `NSTokenField.value` was bound to using the selected range returned by the field editor:

```
@IBAction func deleteSelectedTag(sender: AnyObject) {
    let fieldEditor = (tagTokenField.cell() as! NSCell).fieldEditorForView(tagTokenField)
    if fieldEditor?.selectedRanges.count > 0 {
        let range = fieldEditor!.selectedRanges.first as! NSRange
        fieldEditor!.setSelectedRange(NSMakeRange(0, 0)) // Set to no selection
        selectedNote.tags!.removeRange(range.location..<range.location + range.length)
    }
}
```

After testing I found that selectedRanges always returns just one NSRange with `location` being the token index and `length` the number of selected tokens. At least I didn't find a way to select non contiguous tokens in the NSTokenField.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @objc func deleteToken(_ sender: Any?) {
    if let selectedToken = selectedToken(),
       var tokens = tokenField.objectValue as? [Any],
       let indexToRemove = tokens.firstIndex(where: { $0 as AnyObject === selectedToken as AnyObject }) {
        tokens.remove(at: indexToRemove)
        tokenField.objectValue = tokens
    }
}

func selectedToken() -> Any? {
    guard
        let selectedRange = tokenField.currentEditor()?.selectedRange,
        let tokens = tokenField.objectValue as? [Any]
    else {
        return nil
    }
    
    print("All objects in array: \(tokens.map { String(describing: $0) })")
    
    if selectedRange.location < tokens.count {
        return tokens[selectedRange.location]
    }
    return nil
}
```